# Opening Body Tag in a Component

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component

There may be a better way to do this but right now I am creating a Header and Footer Component.  In the header component I have an opening  ...

SFDC is looking for the closing tag and I cannot save it:

```
The element type "body" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</body>"    
Error: The element type "body" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</body>".
```

Is there any way around this or do I simply need to break up the component a bit more and then include the  in the page itself.

Of course if there is a better way to handle this I would love to hear that as well, open to suggestions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must open and close all tags in a given component or page. Having an opening body tag in a component means you must also have the closing body tag in the component. You can either provide a closing tag in the component, or move the body tag up to each page.

Comment: Thanks -- thats what I figured but just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something simple.